# Printing select results from an array with a while loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, while-loop

So I have this assignment where we build upon a website we created little by little each week. This week I have to write some javascript code that's function is to display a requested number of results from within an array. The number requested is entered in a form text input. The instructions are as follows:

a. Create an input that acts as a fill in the blank for a sentence that prompts the user to
enter the number of job duties they want to see.

b. Create a button that calls a function when clicked (the function created in the next step)

c. Crate a function that takes the user input and assigns the value to a variable.

d. Create an array with at least five job duties in it.

e. Create a new variable and set it equal to the inputted value minus 1

f. Create a while loop that runs while the variable (that represents the index value that we want to print) is greater than or equal to the minimum array value.

g. Within the while loop have two things happen: Have the innerHTML of some element within your page be replaced with the array value that corresponds to the index number that we want printed. You specify the array value by the format arrayname[indexnumber]. Also Have the index subtract one from itself to count down

At this point your function should run, but it does not work properly. Only the array value at the last index is printed. To fix this, we need to concatenate the results of the loop.

i. Create a new variable outside of the loop and set it to be equal to blank

1. You do this by setting it equal to “”

ii. Within the loop, make this variable to be equal to itself plus the array value that we want printed.

iii. Now change the innerHTML to be equal to this variable.

I have this so far yet its not working:

```js
function showDuties() {
  var numDuties = document.getElementById('pfJobs').value;

  var pfDuties = ["Auditing", "Close out registers", "Clean free weights",
    "Sign up new members", "File paperwork"
  ]

  var i = numDuties - 1

  while (i >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('pfj').innerHTML = pfDuties[0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    i--;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here"    onclick="showDuties()"> 
    to see my top 
 <input type="text" id="pfJobs" />
   job duties here.
 <p id = "pfj">
 </p>
</form>
```

What this ends up doing is replacing the text in the paragraph tag in my HTML with an element from within the array, but it only flashes on the screen for half a second then disappears.

I apologize if my formatting is incorrect this is my first time using this site.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Please show the HTML. Edit the question, and then click "edit snippit" to edit it in a convenient editor window. It's part of a [mcve].

Comment: How about a use case? If pfJobs =1 what should be displayed in pfj ?

Comment: If the user entered 1, pfJobs=1 which I would then need to display the element in the array that corresponds to 0 which is why I have the variable i subtract 1.

Comment: this assignment is being made unnecessarily hard by your instructor

Comment: Thats what I thought! It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a copy of a portion of your array and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join these array values into a single string

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showDuties);

function showDuties() {
  var numDuties = document.getElementById('pfJobs').value;

  var pfDuties = ["Auditing", "Close out registers", "Clean free weights", "Sign up new members", "File paperwork"]

  document.getElementById('pfj').innerHTML = pfDuties.slice(0,numDuties).join(", ");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="pfJobs" value="0" max="5">
<button>show jobs</button>

<p id="pfj"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it but depending on what you're trying to do other approaches may be better.  The key is to remember the DOM is dynamic and you can add and subtract nodes from it.

```js
function showDuties() {
  document.getElementById('pj').innerHTML='';
  var numDuties = document.getElementById('pfJobs').value;
  
  var pfDuties = ["Auditing", "Close out registers", "Clean free weights",
    "Sign up new members", "File paperwork"]  
  
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < numDuties; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pfDuties[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
   

// Add the contents 
document.getElementById('pj').appendChild(list);
}
```

```html
<!-- Add HTML Here -->
<div id='pj'></div>
<input id='pfJobs' onchange='showDuties()' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click handler that imitates a form submit without the added hassle. Then capture your value from the input with `document.getElementById`

Then use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or ES6 [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) on the array as those 2 methods don't mutate the original array.

I also added a check that your index will never be more than the length of your array.

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
let pfDuties = ["Auditing", "Close out registers", "Clean free weights",
  "Sign up new members", "File paperwork"
  ];
  let index = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (index > pfDuties.length) {
    document.getElementById('pfj').innerText = 'Value is greater than the number of duties';
    return;
  }
  // slice
  let result = pfDuties.slice(0, index).concat(pfDuties.slice(index + 1));
  // spread
  let result2 = [...pfDuties.slice(0, index), ...pfDuties.slice(index + 1)];
  // you can return either array here just did both to show example
  document.getElementById('pfj').innerHTML = result.join('<br>');
}
```

```html
Value<br>
<input type="text" id="input">
<br><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p id="pfj"></p>
```